# Order query returns invalid ArgumentError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make a query to order an array depending which param the user sends (ASC, DESC) but it is returning:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/productions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-10-22 23:24:18 -0300
Processing by Api::V1::ProductionsController#index as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5946)

ArgumentError (Direction "" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]):
  
app/controllers/api/v1/productions_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Here's the controller:

```rb
class Api::V1::ProductionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_production, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  MAX_PAGINATION_LIMIT = 10

  has_scope :by_title
  has_scope :by_genre

  def index
    @productions = (apply_scopes(Production.limit(limit).offset(params[:offset]))).order(created_at: @order)
    render json: ProductionsRepresenter.new(@productions).as_json
  end

  def show
    render json: ProductionRepresenter.new(@production).as_json
  end 

  def create
    @production = Production.new(production_params)
    if @production.save
      render json: ProductionRepresenter.new(@production).as_json
    else
      render json: @production.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @production.update(production_params)
      render json: ProductionRepresenter.new(@production).as_json, status: 200
    else
      render json: @production.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @production.destroy
  end
  

  private
    def limit
      [params.fetch(:limit, MAX_PAGINATION_LIMIT).to_i].min
    end

    def production_params
      params.permit(:title, :released_date, :score, :image, :production_type, {:character_ids => []}, {:genre_ids => []})
    end

    def set_production
      @production = Production.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
      @order = params.fetch(:order, "ASC") 
    end
    
end
```

I have another controller called for Characters, which is almost the exact same and it does order by properly. I've tried multiple things like replacing the line with `@productions = (Production.all).order(created_at: @order)` (with or without brackets). If I literally put the string like `order(created: 'asc')` it works, but that's not what I need, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Instance variable `@order` is nil because it's only set by calling the method `order_params` which isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the order_params to

```rb
def order

    params.fetch(:order, "ASC") 

end
```

and replaced it in the controller

```rb
@productions = (apply_scopes(Production.limit(limit).offset(params[:offset]))).order(created_at: order)
```

and it somewhat worked, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to solve it. If there is, please let me know

Comment: Looks like a good solution to me. The issue with your original implementation was that @order was never assigned unless order_params was called, which it wasn’t. But I like this solution because it avoids the need for relying on the side effect of assigning the instance var and instead just encapsulates your actual logic.